# PHP Post - Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, xml, post, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am trying to make a POST request to a URL using Curl but getting this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091151/i-am-trying-to-make-a-post-request-to-a-url-using-curl-but-getting-this-error)

I'm trying to make a POST request to a server using curl with some XML included, but I'm getting the error "Request Entity Too Long" Could someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks! :)

```
$url = 'http://web1.trueship.com/readyreturns/company/api.php/orders?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&overwrite=true';

$curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("&xml=".$encodedXml)); 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);     
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
    $result = curl_exec ($curl); 
    curl_close ($curl); 
    print $result;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcurl%5D+Request+Entity+Too+Large

Comment: You get that response from an external service or your service is giving this response?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this message means that the request your trying to process is larger than the server is willing or able to process. You will probably need to configure your php. ini differently

The setup value you will look for is "post_max_size"

if you want to see this value but don't have access to your php set up, write a simple php page with a `<? phpinfo() ?>` 
tag in it, it will display the php.ini values of your current configuration. you can then contact your administrator to have it modified