# PHP curl response unserialize issue

Tags: php, serialization, curl

I am getting "***Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1081 bytes***" error while unserializing curl response.

**Curl request page - ping1.php :**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://example.com/test/curl/ping2.php",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo unserialize($result);
?>
```

**Curl response page - ping2.php**

```
<?php
$data=array('test'=>1,'testing'=>2);
echo serialize($data);
?>
```

Comment: Well, what does `$result` contain?

Comment: Well, can you show what it contains? Because that's where the problem is. That's what the error message is about.

Comment: Put `var_dump($result)` in ping1.php and show the output.

Comment: var_dump($result) : http://i.imgur.com/4Mk5fpG.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got your issue .

**ERROR**

When I ran your code and saw the result  I got

```
string '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
The requested resource<br />/experimentation/Stack/stack.php<br />
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in
the request exceeds the capacity limit.
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
a:2:{s:4:"test";i:1;s:7:"testing";i:2;}' (length=474)
```

**WHY AM I GETTING THIS ERROR?**

You are getting this error beacause you are using `CURLOPT_POST` but not sending any post data . Rather than explaining it here I will refer you to this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091151/i-am-trying-to-make-a-post-request-to-a-url-using-curl-but-getting-this-error) which is base of your issue.

**RESOLUTION**

`CURLOPT_POST` is not required since we are not posting any data .

Here is your working code

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://example.com/test/curl/ping2.php",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r(unserialize($result)) ;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the $result variable contains an error message, so it can't be unserialized

also, be careful with closing tags in ping2.php as it may include extra unwanted spaces